# Sparql Select only one label and comment of classes

Tags: select, uri, sparql, semantic-web

I am trying to select one label and comment of classes but group by doesn't work as expected. The following query is an example of the select.

```
SELECT ?class ?label ?comment WHERE
{

  {SELECT DISTINCT ?class WHERE { {?uri rdf:type ?class}UNION {?class rdf:type owl:Class} UNION {?class rdf:type rdfs:Class} }OFFSET 0 LIMIT 100}

.optional{?class rdfs:label ?label}

.optional{?class rdfs:comment ?comment}

}GROUP BY ?class
```

The goal is to to have every class uri with one label and comment
But am getting results as :

```
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Activity    "attività"@it   
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Activity    "活動"@ja
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Your query is actually illegal - it uses non-aggregate, non-group key in the outer SELECT.

You need to use "SAMPLE" to one pick (random) item from a group if you think there might be multiple labels or comments.

```sql
SELECT ?class (sample(?labelX) as ?label) (sample(?commentX) as ?comment) WHERE
{
   SELECT DISTINCT ?class {
      {?uri rdf:type ?class} UNION
      {?class rdf:type owl:Class} UNION
      {?class rdf:type rdfs:Class}
   } LIMIT 100

   optional{?class rdfs:label ?labelX}
   optional{?class rdfs:comment ?commentX}
} GROUP BY ?class
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is perfect  for sparql 1.1. On the other hand the query don’t work  on DBpedia Sparql Endpoint because they don’t support “SAMPLE” command and the Virtuoso don’t support all of SPARQL 1.1. Is there a possible alternative solution for sparql 1.0 ?
Thank you for your concideration.

Comment: @AndyS This query is illegal as well because braces are missing around the sub-SELECT.

Comment: @vaggeliskls This is not true, Virtuoso 7.x supports SPARQL 1.1 and therefore also SAMPLE keyword.

Comment: You are both right. It was my wrong. I tried it on http://el.dbpedia.org/sparql. However when i tested the result on http://dbpedia.org/sparql the result is not the expected. It presents one uri with all labels and comments of the uri and no only one label and comment of every class. If i have done something wrong please inform me. Thanks again